# Export Html table with css and arabic data also show to excel in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, excel

I have following table in asp.net and I want to generate excel with css and arabic data also show in reoprt.I am using following but not arabic data appear in my Excel and not arabic data appear in my css.I am using asp.net c#

```
Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ExcelFile.xls"); Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter(); HtmlTextWriter 
                    hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw); tblid.RenderControl(hw);
                Response.Write(tw.ToString());
                Response.End();



<style type="text/css" >
    .repFont
    {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: 53px;
    }
        table {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-spacing:0px;

        }
         td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-spacing:0px;
        font-size:11PX;
        text-align:center;
        padding: 0px;
    }

        .auto-style1 {
            height: 27px;
        }
            .bgtd1 {
                background-color:#FFFF99;
            }
            .title {
                color:#CC3333;
            }
            .titleMale {
            color:#3366FF;
            }
            .titleTotal {
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:12PX;
            }
            .maintitle {
             font-size:12px;

            }
            .maintileArabic {

                color:#CC3333;
                padding-left: 187px;
            }
            .maintileEng {

                color:#3366FF;
                padding-left: 113px;
                 padding-bottom: 11px;
            }

        </style>    
    <table id="tblid" runat="server"  border="1" >
          <tr class="bgtd1">
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="title">Region</td>
            <td  colspan="3" class="title"><span id="result_box" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">المجموع العام</span></td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title"> سلطانالخارج</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="title">مسندم</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="title"><span id="result_box2" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">منطقة</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bgtd1">
            <td  colspan="3" class="auto-style1">Grand Total</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">
                &nbsp;Musandam&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;Al-wusta&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;Alburaimi&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;Al-Dhahira&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;Dohfar&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Al-dhakhila&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;Al-sharqiya(n)&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;Al-sharqiyah&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;Albatiniah(s)&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;Al-Albatinah&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;Muscat&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="bgtd1">Gender</td>
            <td class="title"><span id="result_box8" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">&nbsp;مجموع&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td >١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td >١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td >١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td >١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td>١</td>
            <td class="titleMale" >ذ</td>
            <td >١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td >١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td >١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td >١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td>١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td>١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td>١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td >١</td>
            <td class="titleMale">ذ</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="bgtd1"><span id="result_box3" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">جنس</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="bgtd1">Specialization</td>
            <td class="title">Total</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td class="titleMale">M</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="bgtd1" ><span id="result_box4" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">تخصص</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td  rowspan="4" class="bgtd1"><div class="repFont bgtd1">Foundation</div></td>
            <td class="bgtd1">Engnieering</td>
            <td >120</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td class="titleMale">72</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td class="bgtd1">الهندسة&nbsp;</td>
            <td  rowspan="4" class="bgtd1"><div  class="repFont ">&nbsp;مؤسسة&nbsp;</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="bgtd1">Information Technology</td>
            <td>213</td>
            <td>147</td>
            <td class="titleMale">66</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td >1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td class="bgtd1">&nbsp;تكنولوجيا المعلومات&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="bgtd1"><span class="titleTotal">Total</span></td>
            <td rowspan="2">313</td>
            <td >195</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">138</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">2</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td  class="titleMale">0</td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="bgtd1" >إجمالي</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">313</td>
            <td colspan="2">3</td>
            <td colspan="2">0</td>
            <td colspan="2">4</td>
            <td colspan="2">0</td>
            <td colspan="2">4</td>
            <td colspan="2">0</td>
            <td colspan="2">4</td>
            <td colspan="2">0</td>
            <td colspan="2">4</td>
            <td colspan="2">0</td>
            <td colspan="2">4</td>
            <td colspan="2">0</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Did I understand you right, you want to append CSS in your Excel file when you download it and display it in your browser? It's impossible. You should rather style your excel by hand or with any library for excel files before you let it download. CSS and SpreadSheet are totally different things.

Comment: YES.I want when I download excel file css is should be appeared with arabic data.But in my case css is not appearing

Comment: It important, read my updated comment.

Comment: but arabic data is also not appearing why

Comment: because you cannot simply convert your HTML and CSS output into an excel file when you attach an imaginary file that will be downloaded. Actually attaching a file will download something that already exist on the server. If you want to provide a dynamic and styled excel file you should build one first. Take a look at the Open XML SDK if you require it to contain dynamic data.

Comment: can you share any link

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371203/Creating-basic-Excel-workbook-with-Open-XML There is even a tool in the SDK Suite that allows you to generate code from a file, then you simply have to modify the dynamic parts. You should really train yourself in using Google. Please.